# Any advice for my HANGMAN game with PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, hangman

Could you please tell me if there's anything I could improve in my Hangman Game ?

I made this Hangman Game in PyCharm and been improving and adding features for some time. It would be nice if someone from outside could look and find possible bugs or point what else could be improved.
There's GitHub repo: https://github.com/paichiwo/Hangman_GUI

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Hangman_GUI main game file with application layout and game logic

# *** ADD FEATURE - High Score
# ** Make start button nicer
# * Check if is possible to add image or something while loading from API

from Wordlist import world_list
import PySimpleGUI as psg
import random
import string
import requests
import webbrowser

version = "beta"

# Dictionary with all images used in the game
hangman_img = {
    10: "img/Hangman_10.png",
    9: "img/Hangman_09.png",
    8: "img/Hangman_08.png",
    7: "img/Hangman_07.png",
    6: "img/Hangman_06.png",
    5: "img/Hangman_05.png",
    4: "img/Hangman_04.png",
    3: "img/Hangman_03.png",
    2: "img/Hangman_02.png",
    1: "img/Hangman_01.png",
    0: "img/Hangman_00.png",
    "splash": "img/splash.png",
    "close": "img/close.png"
}

# Customization
# Install "RobotoMono-Regular.ttf" (main folder) for best experience, but app will still work without it :)
font_used = ('Roboto Mono', 10)
# Change theme
psg.theme("black")


def secret_word_api():
    # Get secret word from API and choose only words <= 12 characters long
    url = "https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word"
    response = requests.get(url)
    text = response.json()
    word = text[0]
    if len(word) <= 12:
        return word
    else:
        return secret_word_api()


def word_api_or_random():
    # Error handling in case API didn't work for some reason
    try:
        word = secret_word_api().upper()
    # Error handling
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        word = random.choice(world_list).upper()
    except requests.HTTPError:
        word = random.choice(world_list).upper()
    except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
        word = random.choice(world_list).upper()
    return word


def check_word_meaning_link(word):
    # Create link to check the meaning of the secret word
    url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={word.lower()}+meaning"
    return url


def splash_screen():
    # Define the layout for the splash screen
    splash_layout = [
        [psg.Image(hangman_img["splash"])],
        [psg.Button("START", font=(font_used[0], 16),
                    border_width=0,
                    key="-START-",
                    button_color="white")],
        [psg.VPush()],
        [psg.Text(f"Version: {version}", font=(font_used[0], 9))],
        [psg.Text("Click to visit my GitHub",
                  font=font_used, text_color="light green",
                  enable_events=True, key="-LINK-")]
    ]
    # Create the splash screen window
    splash_window = psg.Window('Splash', splash_layout,
                               size=(300, 570),
                               element_justification="center",
                               finalize=True,
                               no_titlebar=True,
                               grab_anywhere=True,
                               keep_on_top=True)
    # Show the splash screen and wait for the start button to be pressed
    while True:
        event, values = splash_window.read()
        if event == "-START-":
            break
        elif event in "-LINK-":
            webbrowser.open("https://github.com/paichiwo")

    # Close the splash screen window
    splash_window.close()


def game_window(points):
    # Main Game Layout
    game_layout = [
        [psg.VPush()],
        [psg.Push(), psg.Image("img/close.png",  # Close button
                               pad=0, enable_events=True, key="-CLOSE-")],
        [psg.VPush()],
        [psg.Image((hangman_img[10]), key="-HANGMAN-")],
        [psg.Text("", key="-WORD-", font=(font_used[0], 25))],
        [psg.Text("USED LETTERS:", font=font_used)],
        [psg.Text("", key="-USED-LETTERS-", font=(font_used, 9))],
        [psg.Text("LIVES", font=font_used),
         psg.Text("", key="-LIVES-", font=(font_used[0], 16), text_color="green"),
         psg.Push(),
         psg.Text(str(points), key="-POINTS-", font=(font_used[0], 16), text_color="green"),
         psg.Text("POINTS", font=font_used)],
        [psg.Text("GUESS A LETTER:", font=font_used)],
        [psg.Input("", size=(10, 1),
                   enable_events=True,
                   key="-INPUT-")],
        [psg.Button('Submit', visible=False, bind_return_key=True)],
        [psg.Text("", key="-OUTPUT-Msg-", font=font_used, text_color="yellow")],
        [psg.VPush()]
    ]
    # Create main game window
    window = psg.Window("Hangman Game", game_layout,
                        size=(300, 570),
                        element_justification="center",
                        finalize=True,
                        no_titlebar=True,
                        grab_anywhere=True,
                        keep_on_top=True)
    return window


def hangman(points=0):
    # Game logic

    window = game_window(points)

    # list with alphabet
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters
    # secret word
    word = word_api_or_random()
    print(word)
    # create a Google search link for user to check the meaning of the secret word
    link = check_word_meaning_link(word)
    # word letters as list
    word_letters = [letter for letter in word]
    # word blanks as list
    word_blanks = ["_"] * len(word)
    # number of lives
    lives = 10
    # letters already used
    guessed_letters = ""

    window["-WORD-"].update("".join(word_blanks), font=(font_used[0], 25))
    window["-USED-LETTERS-"].update(", ".join(guessed_letters))
    window["-HANGMAN-"].update(hangman_img[lives])
    window["-LIVES-"].update(str(lives))

    # Main Loop
    while lives > 0:

        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (psg.WIN_CLOSED, "-CLOSE-"):
            break

        # accepts only one character, must be from alphabet
        if len(values["-INPUT-"]) > 1 or values["-INPUT-"] not in alphabet:
            # delete last char from input
            window["-INPUT-"].update(values["-INPUT-"][:-1])
        # if enter is pressed
        elif event == 'Submit':
            user_input = window["-INPUT-"].get().upper()
            window['-INPUT-'].update("")

            # Check if user_input in guessed letters
            if user_input not in guessed_letters:
                guessed_letters += user_input
                window["-USED-LETTERS-"].update(", ".join(guessed_letters))

                # Check if user_input is in word_letters list
                if user_input in word_letters:
                    window["-OUTPUT-Msg-"].update("Good guess, letter found")

                    # find indexes of correctly guessed letter
                    for i, letter in enumerate(word_letters):
                        # and replace blanks with letters
                        if word_letters[i] == user_input:
                            word_blanks[i] = word[i]
                    # output updated word
                    window["-WORD-"].update("".join(word_blanks), font=(font_used[0], 25))

                    # win condition
                    if "".join(word_blanks) == "".join(word_letters):
                        points += 1
                        window["-POINTS-"].update(str(points))
                        choice = psg.popup_yes_no(f"YOU WON! \nFind the meaning of: {word} ?\n",
                                                  font=font_used, keep_on_top=True)
                        if choice == "Yes":
                            webbrowser.open(link)
                            window.close()
                            hangman(points)
                        else:
                            window.close()
                            hangman(points)
                # lost condition
                else:
                    lives = lives - 1
                    window["-OUTPUT-Msg-"].update("Wrong, try again!")
                    window["-HANGMAN-"].update(hangman_img[lives])
                    window["-LIVES-"].update(lives)
                    window["-WORD-"].update("".join(word_blanks), font=(font_used[0], 25))
                    if lives == 0:
                        choice = psg.popup_yes_no(
                            f"YOU LOST! \nDo you want to find the meaning\nof the word: {word} ?\n",
                            font=font_used, keep_on_top=True
                        )
                        if choice == "Yes":
                            webbrowser.open(link)
                            window.close()
                            hangman(points)
                        else:
                            window.close()
                            hangman(points)
            # output if letter already been chosen
            else:
                window["-OUTPUT-Msg-"].update("Letter used already!")

    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    splash_screen()
    hangman()
```

Answer (score 3):

Very nicely written.

---

```
except requests.ConnectionError:
    word = random.choice(world_list).upper()
except requests.HTTPError:
    word = random.choice(world_list).upper()
except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
    word = random.choice(world_list).upper()
return word
```

can be shortened to avoid repetition:

```
except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError):
    word = random.choice(world_list).upper()
```

---

```
if event == "-START-":
    break
elif event in "-LINK-":
    webbrowser.open("https://github.com/paichiwo")
```

There is a typo: `event in "-LINK-"` should be `event == "-LINK-"`, otherwise `event = 'INK'` will satisfy the condition, as membership operator (`in`) on strings checks for substring occurance.

---

```
# Close the splash screen window
splash_window.close()
```

Comments are meant to explain not *what* is happening but *why* it is happening. You should be able to tell *what* is happening just by looking at the code, which is the case here, so the comment is redundant. This can be applied to almost all of the comments in the code.

---

```
word_letters = [letter for letter in word]
```

A function can be used here:

```
word_letters = list(word)
```

---

The structure of your main game loop looks approximately like this:

```
if a:
    ...
    if b:
        ...
        if c:
            ...
        else:
            ...
    else:
        ...
else:
    ...
```

There is a lot of nesting. Nesting decreases readability dramatically, it makes following the flow very hard. This can be dealt with by utilising [early returns](https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8).
Look how the pseudo-code above can be transformed:

```
if not a:
    ...
    return
...
if not b:
    ...
    return
...
if not c:
    ...
    return
...
```

We just decreased maximum indentation level from 3 to 1 and made the flow linear! You can try doing it yourself by handling edge cases first and returning early.

---

```
if choice == "Yes":
    webbrowser.open(link)
    window.close()
    hangman(points)
else:
    window.close()
    hangman(points)
```

Common logic like this can be turned into a function of its own to decrease repetition. Also in this case some lines can be moved out of the condition completely:

```
if choice == "Yes":
    webbrowser.open(link)
window.close()
hangman(points)
```

---

**EDIT to address the comment**

Here is the updated code of the `event == 'Submit'` branch:

```
user_input = window["-INPUT-"].get().upper()
window['-INPUT-'].update("")

if user_input in guessed_letters:
    window["-OUTPUT-Msg-"].update("Letter used already!")
    continue

guessed_letters += user_input
window["-USED-LETTERS-"].update(", ".join(guessed_letters))

# Check if user_input is in word_letters list
if user_input in word_letters:
    window["-OUTPUT-Msg-"].update("Good guess, letter found")

    # find indexes of correctly guessed letter
    for i, letter in enumerate(word_letters):
        # and replace blanks with letters
        if word_letters[i] == user_input:
            word_blanks[i] = word[i]
    # output updated word
    window["-WORD-"].update("".join(word_blanks), font=(font_used[0], 25))

    # win condition
    if "".join(word_blanks) != "".join(word_letters):
        continue

    points += 1
    window["-POINTS-"].update(str(points))
    choice = psg.popup_yes_no(f"YOU WON! \nFind the meaning of: {word} ?\n",
                              font=font_used, keep_on_top=True)
    if choice == "Yes":
        webbrowser.open(link)
    window.close()
    hangman(points)

# lost condition
else:
    lives = lives - 1
    window["-OUTPUT-Msg-"].update("Wrong, try again!")
    window["-HANGMAN-"].update(hangman_img[lives])
    window["-LIVES-"].update(lives)
    window["-WORD-"].update("".join(word_blanks), font=(font_used[0], 25))

    if lives != 0:
        continue

    choice = psg.popup_yes_no(
        f"YOU LOST! \nDo you want to find the meaning\nof the word: {word} ?\n",
        font=font_used, keep_on_top=True
    )
    if choice == "Yes":
        webbrowser.open(link)
    window.close()
    hangman(points)
```

We use `continue` instead of `return` since we want to continue iterating the loop rather than returning from the entire function, maybe you had troubles with this. `return`, `break` and `continue` all alter the control flow, it's important to know where to use which.

Comment: Thank you for such a great answer. I implemented most of your advice however I have massive problem with the early returns. I've been reading and trying to implement but application behaves in a very strange way ( or stops working ). I think I'm not identing statements correctly after using return istead of else: Could you show me one example of how this should be done ?

Comment: @Paichiwo updated the answer